# How to convert UTF16 surrogate pairs to equivalent HEX codepoint in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-16, codepoint

I am making a application, when chat will be sent from iOS app, but the admin could view the chat from Admin panel which is built in PHP.

From DB, I will be getting chat messages like this:

```
Hi, Jax\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude44! can we go for a coffee?
```

I am using twemoji [library](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) which can convert HEX code points into images.

Let's say in detail,

In php section, I have following code:-

```
$text = "This is fun \u1f602! \u1f1e8 ";
$html = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{2,5})/i", "&#x$1;", $text);
echo $html;
```

Now, the twemoji parses the total body of the HTML document to replace Hex code points to images.

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Set the size of the rendered Emojis
  // This can be set to 16x16, 36x36, or 72x72
  twemoji.size = '16x16';

  // Parse the document body and
  // insert <img> tags in place of Unicode Emojis
  twemoji.parse(document.body);
}
```

So, I need the text to replace all UTF-16 to HEX codepoints(for emojis).
**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a double problem:

- Detecting that there is a surrogate pair encoded
- Actually converting that surrogate pair into an HTML entity

Explaining the complexities of the issue goes considerably outside the scope of a single answer (you'd have to read up on UTF-16 for this), but this code fragment seems to solve your problem:

```
$text = "Hi, Jax\\ud83d\\ude1b\\ud83d\\ude44! can we go for a coffee?";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(d[89ab][0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u(d[c-f][0-9a-f]{2})/i', function ($matches) {
    $first = $matches[1];
    $second = $matches[2];
    $value = ((eval("return 0x$first;") & 0x3ff) << 10) | (eval("return 0x$second;") & 0x3ff);
    $value += 0x10000;
    return "&#$value;";
  }, $text);

echo $result;
```

I know that using `eval` is almost always discouraged, but it is perfectly safe in this example due to the regular expression matches (you know that the matches only contain hexadecimal digits).

Comment: Man that was surely a charm... However there are some pairs which aren't getting converted.

Comment: What pairs? Are you sure they are actual pairs and not BMP codepoints (which would be simply encoded as `\uNNNN`, with one escape sequence instead of two)? If this is the case, you'd need to use another regular expression replacement to filter them out. This is very simple, since you simply want to replace `\uNNNN` with `&#xNNNN;` (where `NNNN` are exactly four hexadecimal digits), and it can be done with a simple regex replace.

Comment: Like `\ud83d\ude43`