# Print emoji using UTF-16 decimal php

Tags: php, php-7

So currently I have a string in UTF-16 decimal which I am converting using chr().

It works fine for the most part, but it failing on the emoji.

I ran an example in js which works perfectly, here is that example

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,119,105,116,104,32,97,110,32,101,109,111,106,105,32,55357,56834,32))
```

which produces

```
This is a test with an emoji
```

But when I try do this in PHP this is what I get

```
function fromCharCode() {
    return array_reduce(func_get_args(),function($a,$b){$a.=chr($b);return $a;});
}
print(fromCharCode(84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,97,32,116,101,115,116,32,119,105,116,104,32,97,110,32,101,109,111,106,105,32,55357,56834,32));
```

Result:

```
This is a test with an emoji =
```

Now I have found that js lets me take in `String.fromCharCode(55357,56834)` which produces

but PHP's `chr()` only lets you take in one at a time, which means I cant produce the emoji.

Does anyone know a way to do this by fixing the current code or doing it using a different function?

Edit: So you get some more background, The string I originally have to start with is a HEX UTF-16
`005400680069007300200069007300200061002000740065007300740020007700690074006800200061006E00200065006D006F006A00690020D83DDE020020`

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: So why aren't you using UTF-8? That would make things considerably easier. E.g. `echo mb_chr(128514);`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226593/how-to-convert-utf16-surrogate-pairs-to-equivalent-hex-codepoint-in-php

Comment: Sadly I dont have the option to use UTF-8, the data I have to use is UTF-16

Comment: Can you describe what data that is? Because it sounds almost inconceivable something would require UTF16 data at this point in time.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So I have a hardware device that spits out data to me in the format shown(UTF-16 HEX originally before I touch it) at the bottom of the post. I just need to display this on screen in anyway possible that will also allow for the emojis to be rendered.

Comment: Okay, so what you describe is that you _get_ data in UTF16 encoding, but why does it need to _stay_ UTF16? Use [iconv](https://www.phrp.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to turn the input into UTF8 and then stick with that? Why would the output also need to be UTF16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working this way

```
echo utf16HexToUtf8("005400680069007300200069007300200061002000740065007300740020007700690074006800200061006E00200065006D006F006A00690020D83DDE020020");

function utf16HexToUtf8($data){
    return preg_replace_callback('/(d[89ab][0-9a-f]{2})(d[c-f][0-9a-f]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/i', function ($matches) {
        return mb_convert_encoding( hex2bin($matches[0]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
    }, $data);
}
```

Output:

```
This is a test with an emoji
```

It converts it from a big long HEX string to binary and then converts it to UTF-8 from UTF-16

As per the original example/question, that would need to be converted to a HEX string from the current UTF-16 array of ints

Comment: Dude. Don't reinvent the wheel, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php exists, with its entire reason for existing is converting one text encoding into another.